# How to join by most recent preceding date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, join

Imagine I have a database with historic price data and a second table with dates

```
Item | Price | Date               Customer | Item | date
-------------------------         ---------------------------
   A | 2.49$ | 2014-09-01                1 |    A | 2014-08-27
   B | 1.29$ | 2014-09-01                2 |    A | 2014-09-02
   A | 2.99$ | 2014-08-25                
   B | 1.39$ | 2014-08-26
```

A new row was entered into the price history table every time the price changed.

How can I (efficiently) join the two tables so that I can get the price each customer had to pay on that day?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2cec)

Comment: Can you, please, post a sample schema and data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Are you able to alter the schema of this database? I ask because it would be much better if you a start and end date on the price table.

Comment: No, this is a simplified example. In the real world the price list is being exported weekly for all items, and if a week is missing I want to fall back to the data of the previous week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from dbo.Sales s
  cross apply (
  select top (1) *
  from dbo.PriceHistory ph where ph.itemId = s.ItemId and ph.Date <= s.Date
  order by ph.Date desc
) ca;
```